# Check if a sentence contains two or more words from my list

Tags: python, list

Thanks for the quick and great help everytime i post questions here!:)

Hope all you have great days!

My questions is how can i check whether a sentence contains two or more words from my list

For example

> mylist = ['apple', 'banana', 'monkey', 'love']
>
> Sentence1 = "Monkeys love bananas"
>
> -> as monkey, love, banana those three words are in list I want to get this sentence 1 as positive
>
> Sentence2 = "The dog loves cats"
>
> -> since sentence2 only contains the word "love" from my list, I want to get this sentence2 as negative

I learned that in case of checking whether a sentence contains any single word in list, I could use

if any (e in text for e in wordset):

However, i could not find the solution that could deal with the problem stated above.

Could anyone give help?

(As there are bunch of sentences that are not using English, It would be very hard to use NLP tools, such as stemming or lemmantizing)

Answer (score 6):

You need to iterate through your `mylist` and check if the word in mylist is present in your sentence. If present put that into a list and find the length. If the length is >= 2 then positive!

```
>>> mylist = ['apple', 'banana', 'monkey', 'love']
>>> s1 = "Monkeys love bananas"    
>>> len([each for each in mylist if each.lower() in s1.lower()])>=2
True
>>> s2="The dog loves cats"
>>> len([each for each in mylist if each.lower() in s2.lower()])>=2
False
```

The same using lambda,

```
>>> checkPresence = lambda mylist,s : len([each for each in mylist if each.lower() in s.lower()])>=2
>>> checkPresence(mylist,s1)
True
>>> checkPresence(mylist,s2)
False
```

Comment: Yes, A filter is the way to go

Comment: This code will fail since you still have `Monkeys` in sentence 1 and `monkey` in the list. `Monkey` needs to be make lowercase.

Comment: Not really! The sample IO hasnt considered the case sensitivity and plurals.

Comment: While your solution is very concise, the OP still mentions that `monkey` is one of the words that exits in `Sentence1` and thus should be counted.

Comment: Yeah I get it. Just realised. I've added the edits for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
mylist = ['apple', 'banana', 'monkey', 'love']
sentence1 = "Monkeys love bananas"
final_val = 1 if sum(i in sentence1.lower() for i in mylist) > 1 else -1
```

Output:

```
1
```

Test 2:

```
mylist = ['apple', 'banana', 'monkey', 'love']
sentence2 = "The dog loves cats"
final_val = 1 if sum(i in sentence2.lower() for i in mylist) > 1 else -1
print(final_val)
```

Output:

```
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the other *pythonic* answers, here is a plain (possibly fast) way:

```
>>> mylist = ['apple', 'banana', 'monkey', 'love']
>>> def in_my_list(sentence):
        found = 0
        sentence = sentence.lower()
        for word in mylist:
            if word in sentence:
                found += 1
            if found==2:
                return True
        return False

>>> sentence1 = "Monkeys love bananas"
>>> sentence2 = "The dog loves cats"
>>> in_my_list(sentence1)
True
>>> in_my_list(sentence2)
False
```

It does not check all words in `mylist`; hence faster than `len`/`sum` versions.